# How to add contact from email?

Tags: contacts

Someone sends me an email with a phone number, address, etc.  I want to add it to my contacts.  I'd think it would be somewhat simple, but it is quite difficult.

I can click on the phone number, call it, hang up before it rings (ick!), go to call history, long click on the number , then add to contacts.
Of course then I still have to manually type in the address, etc. Going back to the email and cutting and pasting as multiple operations isn't so nice either.

Is there an easy and efficient way to do this?  Some app maybe?  Or am I just doing it wrong?

<sup>If relevant, my device is a T-Mobile myTouch 3G Slide with Android 2.1</sup>

Comment: which version of android do you have?

Comment: 2.1, on the mytouch slide from t-mobile.

Comment: Easy as pie to do it in Gmail webapp.

Answer (score 1):

If you long-press the phone number, you'll get prompted to add a contact. Unfortunately you still need to manually enter a lot of information.

Comment: Tried that first, didn't do it.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't look like a phone number, Android probably can't parse it.

Comment: it parses it as a phone number, so i can call it.  Have to hang up before it rings, then add to contact.  That works (although ugly), but still left with the problem of how to add the rest of the info easily.

Comment: Mine doesn't do it that way; I get options when I long-press a phone number. But even then it's not all that helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this app "Contact adder". First you copy the signature and then open this app. It allows you to Simply map these fields with contact book. It also auto detects email address if it is in the signature.

[Contact adder, Trial version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aks.contactaddertrial) and [Contact adder, Pro version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aks.contactadderpro)

Answer (score 0):

Its majorly dependent on your launcher, you could replace your default dialer with GO! dialer or something of that sort. Most stock launchers have this functionality, once you click on the number in the email, it would open it in the dialer there press the option button and you would have add contact. If not, try alternative dialers as mentioned.